# Within a sparse-array data-structure how does one retrieve the real position count of such a structure's item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse array of array entries/items as follows ...

```
var indexed = new Array();

indexed["5"] = [35, 2];
indexed["3"] = [20, 2];
indexed["4"] = [25, 3];
```

I want to find ***something like the "real" position count*** of an entry/item within such a sparse array structure by providing an item's array index( respectively its key).

Expected results:

- If one does provide `3` (either as string or number value) the returned (index) value should be the number value `0`.
- If one does provide `4` (either as string or number value) the returned (index) value should be the number value `1`.
- If one does provide `5` (either as string or number value) the returned (index) value should be the number value `2`.
- In case of an unsuccessful search the return value should be the number value `-1`.

Comment: Can you please provide your attempt and add your data as a formatted code block rather than an image?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Show code and example data as properly formatted text (so it can easily be copy&pasted for testing), and not just images of them. Also please explain, what you have tried so far – this site is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @Invisible55 ... Are there any questions left regarding the last edit's latest approach? Seriously it was nice if you could give a final feedback to, what I believe is, the final solution. Dropping a not that well described problem, getting help through many iterations, but not leaving a final feedback is not the most polite behavior. In addition it was nice if you could find and click the button which accepts the to the OP most useful answer in case the last provided solution was the one you were looking for from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

A valid approach was to search the array by its [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method. The callback method then needs to implement the matching criteria, which is ... *does the currently processed array item has the key, one is looking for* ...

```
obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
```

`find` then does return either the (first) matching object or it returns the `undefined` value. For the latter case, in order to prevent accessing a property of `undefined`, one might use the [optional chaining/`?.` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

A final solution then might look similar to the next provided one ...

```js
const sampleList = [{
  '2': [1, 3],
}, {
  '3': [1, 4],
}, {
  '4': [2, 6],
}];

function getFirstItemOfObjectByKey(arr, key) {
  return (arr.find(obj =>
    obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
  ))?.[key][0];
}

console.log(
  getFirstItemOfObjectByKey(sampleList, 4) // expected: 2
);
console.log(
  getFirstItemOfObjectByKey(sampleList, 3) // expected: 1
);
console.log(
  getFirstItemOfObjectByKey(sampleList, 1) // expected: undefined
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case one is forced to work with a somehow abusively used sparse array structure, like the OP is experiencing it, the above approach slightly changes to ...

```js
var abusedSparseArray = new Array();

abusedSparseArray["3"] = [20, 2];
abusedSparseArray["4"] = [25, 3];
abusedSparseArray["5"] = [35, 2];

function getFirstItemOfArrayEntryByEntryKey(arr, key) {
  return (arr.find((entry, idx) =>
    idx === key
  ) || [])[0];
}

console.log(
  getFirstItemOfArrayEntryByEntryKey(abusedSparseArray, 3) // expected: 20
);
console.log(
  getFirstItemOfArrayEntryByEntryKey(abusedSparseArray, 4) // expected: 25
);
console.log(
  getFirstItemOfArrayEntryByEntryKey(abusedSparseArray, 5) // expected: 35
);
console.log(
  getFirstItemOfArrayEntryByEntryKey(abusedSparseArray, 1) // expected: undefined
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

As it finally turns out the OP wants to know the *somehow real position count* of an entry/item within a sparse array by looking for such an entry's `index`ed `key` within such a sparse array structure.

In this case one has to treat the sparse array like an ordinary (key-value) object. Passing such an object to [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), one gets an array of entries, where each entry is an array which holds two items, the entry-key and the entry-value. Now one just needs to *find the index* / [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the sparse array item's key one is looking for ...

```js
const sparseArray = new Array();

sparseArray["5"] = [35, 2];
sparseArray["3"] = [20, 2];
sparseArray["4"] = [25, 3];

function getRealPositionCountOfSparseArrayEntryByKey(arr, key) {
  key = String(key);
  return Object
    .entries(arr)
    .findIndex(entry => entry[0] === key);
}

console.log(
  getRealPositionCountOfSparseArrayEntryByKey(sparseArray, 3) // expected: 0
);
console.log(
  getRealPositionCountOfSparseArrayEntryByKey(sparseArray, 4) // expected: 1
);
console.log(
  getRealPositionCountOfSparseArrayEntryByKey(sparseArray, 5) // expected: 2
);
console.log(
  getRealPositionCountOfSparseArrayEntryByKey(sparseArray, 1) // expected: -1
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help. However the solution does not work in my case, because your function works with an array of objects. My problem is based on an array of arrays. My first array is indexed, and the seconds one is associative.
Maybe you have an idea for my problem ? Thank you.

Comment: @Invisible55 ... Believe me, there is not such a thing like an *associative array* in JavaScript. The main object structure of this language anyhow boils down to *a bag of key value pairs*. You are free to edit your question again and provide a sample of the nested data structure you are dealing with. Only then one can run and debug the code in order to find the cause of why the above solution does not do its intended job. My guess so far ... your JS engine/environment does not support the `?.` operator.

Comment: var indexed = new Array();
indexed ["3"] = [20, 2];
indexed ["4"] = [25, 3];
indexed ["5"] = [35, 2];

This is how it look like, array in array, one is indexed, the other is associative. No objects.

Comment: Finally got it, ... but are you aware that this structure is of no use, since the digit based keys that are provided to a sparse array each equal the exact `index`ed position within such a sparse array? Given `var indexed = new Array();` and `indexed ["3"] = [20, 2];` and then iterating such an array will give you the number value `3` as `index` of this array's single item/entry. I now know, what you want to achieve. But I'd rather fix the decision of using such a data structure in a non appropriate way.

Comment: I think I screwed up the array definition in the question because originally I have overwritten the indexed array keys. Now I corrected it, and you can see Im pushing the associative arrays into the indexed. 
Your code does not work with this, but I think you are very close. Now it gets undefined with this data structure. Maybe you can make it work now.

Comment: Nope, you screwed it up with the last edit. I'm going to fix the question and the provided example code for the last time. I changed the topic as well, in order to reflect what you really want(ed) to achieve. The last edit of my answer provides the final solution to your problem. But I still advice you to not (ab)use `Array` instances by treating them like real `Object` types.

Comment: @Invisible55 ... are there any questions left regarding the last edit's latest approach?